# How can I append string to list (array) globally?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have created a Quiz application in PyQt4 and added "hearts" as Health points, There is Heart, Heart1 and Heart2. I also added Heartlosscount list, which determines if user losses and shows how many hearts are left.

```
    global heartlosscount
    heartlosscount = []


    def somefunction():
        if len(heartlosscount) == 1:
           self.heart2.hide()
           heartlosscount.append(2)
        elif len(heartlosscount) == 2:
           self.heart2.hide()
           self.heart1.hide()
           heartlosscount.append(3)
        elif len(heartlosscount) == 3:
           self.heart2.hide()
           self.heart1.hide()
           self.heart.hide()
        else: 
           self.heart2.hide()
           heartlosscount.append(1)
           print len(heartlosscount)
```

It prints 1 in console. (Means heart loss count is 1)

Whenever user goes on second question, all hearts appear. As solution for that, I added this to question2 function:

```
    if len(heartlosscount) == 1:
        self.heart2.hide()
    elif len(heartlosscount) == 2:
        self.heart2.hide()
        self.heart1.hide()
    elif len(heartlosscount) == 3:
        self.heart2.hide()
        self.heart1.hide()
        self.heart.hide()
    else: 
        print len(heartlosscount)
```

This would print nothing in console (means its null).

---

## Full Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import resources
from functools import partial


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle("E.S Quiz")
        #self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/newPrefix/download.jpeg'))
        self.home()


    def home(self):
        self.pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.pic.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        self.pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Background.png"))
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("", self)
        self.btn.resize(150, 120)
        self.btn.move(550, 400)
        self.btn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btn.setObjectName('btn')
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("#btn {background-image: url(':/images/Button1.png'); border: none; }"
        "#btn:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Button1Hover.png'); }"
        "#btn:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Button1Press.png'); }")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.page1)
        self.sun = QtGui.QLabel("", self)
        movie = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Sun.gif")
        self.sun.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        self.sun.move(10, -100)
        self.sun.resize(300, 300)
        global heartlosscount
        heartlosscount = []
        self.show()
        self.raise_()






    def page1(self):
        self.pic.hide()
        self.btn.hide()
        self.sun.hide()
        self.pic2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.pic2.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        self.pic2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Menu1.png"))
        self.char1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.char1.setObjectName('Char1')
        self.char1.setStyleSheet("#Char1 {background-image: url(':/images/Char1'); border: none; }"
        "#Char1:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Char1_1.png'); }") 
        self.char1.setGeometry(150, 200, 265, 240)    
        self.char2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.char2.setObjectName('Char2')
        self.char2.setStyleSheet("#Char2 {background-image: url(':/images/Char2.png'); border: none; }"
        "#Char2:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Char2_2.png'); }")    
        self.char2.setGeometry(500, 200, 265, 240)  
        self.char3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.char3.setObjectName('Char3')
        self.char3.setStyleSheet("#Char3 {background-image: url(':/images/Char3.png'); border: none; }"
        "#Char3:hover {background-image: url(':/images/Char3_3.png'); }")   
        self.char3.setGeometry(850, 200, 265, 240) 
        self.unlimited = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.unlimited.setObjectName('Unlimited')              
        self.unlimited.setStyleSheet("#Unlimited {background-image: url(':/images/Unlimited.png'); border: none; }"
        "#Unlimited:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Unlimited_1.png'); }"
        "#Unlimited:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Unlimited_2.png'); }")
        self.unlimited.setGeometry(480, 500, 300, 100)
        self.char1.clicked.connect(self.question1) 
        self.pic4 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.pic4.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Incorrect.png"))
        self.goback = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.goback.setObjectName('goback')
        self.goback.setStyleSheet("#goback {background-image: url(':/images/Goback.png'); border: none; }"
        "#goback:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Goback1.png'); }"
        "#goback:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Goback2.png'); }")
        self.goback.show()
        self.goback.setGeometry(0, 610, 300, 100)
        self.goback.show()     
        self.goback.clicked.connect(self.gobackfunc)                                                                                           
        self.pic2.show()
        self.char1.show()
        self.char2.show()
        self.char3.show()
        self.unlimited.show()

    def question1(self):
        self.pic2.hide()
        self.char1.hide()
        self.char2.hide()
        self.char3.hide()
        self.unlimited.hide()
        self.pic3 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.pic3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Night.png"))
        self.pic3.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        self.que1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.que1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Question1.png"))
        self.que1.setGeometry(50, 70, 800, 300)
        self.answ = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.answ.setObjectName('answ')
        self.setStyleSheet("#answ {background-image: url(':/images/Answ1.png'); border: none; }"
        "#answ:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Answ1_1.png'); }")
        self.answ.setGeometry(0, 350, 500, 400)
        self.answ1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.answ1.setObjectName('answ1')
        self.answ1.setStyleSheet("#answ1 {background-image: url(':/images/Answ2.png'); border: none; }"
        "#answ1:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Answ2_2.png'); }")
        self.answ1.setGeometry(400, 350, 500, 400)
        self.answ1.clicked.connect(partial(self.incorrect, self.answ1))
        self.answ1.clicked.connect(partial(self.scorecheck, self.answ1))
        self.answ1.clicked.connect(partial(self.checkifout, self.answ1))
        self.answ2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.answ2.setObjectName('answ2')
        self.answ2.setStyleSheet("#answ2 {background-image: url(':/images/Answ3.png'); border: none; }"
        "#answ2:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Answ3_3.png'); }")
        self.answ2.setGeometry(800, 350, 500, 400)
        self.answ.clicked.connect(partial(self.incorrect, self.answ))
        self.answ.clicked.connect(partial(self.scorecheck, self.answ))
        self.answ.clicked.connect(partial(self.checkifout, self.answ))
        self.answ2.clicked.connect(partial(self.Correct, self.answ2))
        self.answ2.clicked.connect(partial(self.scorecheck, self.answ2))
        self.pic5 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.pic5.setObjectName('pic5')
        self.pic5.setStyleSheet("#pic5 { background-image: url(':/images/Timeout.png'); border: none; }")
        self.pic5.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        self.pic6 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.pic6.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Correct.png"))
        self.pic6.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        #self.heart = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        #hearts = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
        #self.heart.setMovie(hearts)
        #hearts.start()
        #self.heart.move(20, 0)
        #self.heart.resize(50, 50)
       # self.heart1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
       # hearts1 = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
       # self.heart1.setMovie(hearts1)
       # hearts1.start()
       # self.heart1.move(80, 0)
       # self.heart1.resize(50, 50)
       # self.heart2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
       # hearts2 = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
       # self.heart2.setMovie(hearts2)
       # hearts2.start()
       # self.heart2.move(140, 0)
       # self.heart2.resize(50, 50)
        self.tmr = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.tmr.setSingleShot(True)
        self.tmr.timeout.connect(partial(self.Timeout, self.tmr))
        self.tmr.start(12000)
        self.timer = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        timer1 = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Timer.gif")
        self.timer.setMovie(timer1)
        timer1.start()
        self.timer.setGeometry(850, 0, 350, 250)
        self.timer.show()
        self.pic3.show()
        self.que1.show()
        self.answ.show()
        self.answ1.show()
        self.answ2.show()
        self.heartlist()
        self.heart.show()
        self.heart1.show()
        self.heart2.show()




    def incorrect(self, sendercheck):
        self.timer.hide()
        self.tmr.stop()
        self.pic3.hide()
        self.que1.hide()
        self.answ.hide()
        self.answ1.hide()
        self.answ2.hide()
        self.pic4.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        self.pic4.show()
        self.cont = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.cont.setObjectName('cont')
        self.cont.setStyleSheet("#cont {background-image: url(':/images/Continue.png'); border: none; }"
        "#cont:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Continue1.png'); }"
        "#cont:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Continue2.png'); }")
        self.cont.setGeometry(980, 610, 300, 300)
        self.cont.clicked.connect(self.incorrecthandler)
        self.goback.show() 
        if sendercheck == self.answ:
            self.cont.show()
        if sendercheck == self.answ1:
            self.cont.show()
        else:
            pass


        if self.heart2.isHidden():
            self.heart1.hide()
            heartlosscount.append(1)
        elif self.heart1.isHidden():
            self.heart.hide()
            heartlosscount.append(2)
        else:
            self.heart2.hide()
            heartlosscount.append(3)





    def Timeout(self, sendercheck):
        self.timer.hide()
        self.cont1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.cont1.setObjectName('cont1')
        self.cont1.setStyleSheet("#cont1 {background-image: url(':/images/Continue.png'); border: none; }"
        "#cont1:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Continue1.png'); }"
        "#cont1:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Continue2.png'); }")
        self.cont1.setGeometry(980, 610, 300, 300)
        self.cont1.clicked.connect(self.timeouthandler)
        self.goback2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.goback2.setObjectName('goback2')
        self.goback2.setStyleSheet("#goback2 {background-image: url(':/images/Goback.png'); border: none; }"
        "#goback2:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Goback1.png'); }"
        "#goback2:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Goback2.png'); }")
        self.goback2.clicked.connect(self.gobackfunc)
        self.goback2.setGeometry(0, 610, 300, 100)
        self.pic3.hide()
        self.que1.hide()
        self.answ.hide()
        self.answ1.hide()
        self.answ2.hide()
        self.pic5.show()
        self.tmr.stop()
        self.goback2.show()
        self.cont1.show() 
        self.heartlist()
        self.goback.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)
        self.heart3.show()
        self.heart4.show()
        self.heart5.show()
        if len(heartlosscount) == 1:
            self.heart5.hide()
            self.heart4.hide()
            heartlosscount.append(2)
            print "too"
        elif len(heartlosscount) == 2:
            self.heart5.hide()
            self.heart4.hide()
            self.heart3.hide()
            heartlosscount.append(3)
            print "ones upon"
        else: 
            self.heart5.hide()
            heartlosscount.append(1)
            print "theres no reason"



        self.checkifout(self)



    def Correct(self, sendercheck):
        self.tmr.stop()
        self.pic6.show()
        self.goback.show()
        self.pic3.hide()
        self.que1.hide()
        self.answ.hide()
        self.answ1.hide()
        self.answ2.hide()
        self.cont2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.cont2.setObjectName("Cont2")
        self.cont2.setStyleSheet("#Cont2 {background-image: url(':/images/Continue.png'); border: none; }"
        "#Cont2:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Continue1.png'); }"
        "#Cont2:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Continue2.png'); }")
        self.cont2.setGeometry(980, 610, 300, 300)
        self.cont2.show()
        self.goback3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.goback3.setObjectName('goback3')
        self.goback3.setStyleSheet("#goback3 {background-image: url(':/images/Goback.png'); border: none; }"
        "#goback3:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Goback1.png'); }"
        "#goback3:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Goback2.png'); }")
        self.goback3.setGeometry(0, 610, 300, 100)
        self.goback3.show()
        self.goback3.clicked.connect(self.gobackfunc)
        self.cont2.clicked.connect(self.correcthandler)
        self.heart.show()
        self.heart1.show()
        self.heart2.show()
        if len(heartlosscount) == 1:
            self.heart2.hide()
        if len(heartlosscount) == 2:
            self.heart2.hide()
            self.heart1.hide()
        if len(heartlosscount) == 3:
            self.heart2.hide()
            self.heart1.hide()
            self.heart.hide()
        else: 
            print len(heartlosscount)






    def checkifout(self, sendercheck):
        if len(heartlosscount) == 3:
            self.gameover()
        else:
            pass 



    def heartlist(self):
        self.heart = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        hearts = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
        self.heart.setMovie(hearts)
        hearts.start()
        self.heart.move(20, 0)
        self.heart.resize(50, 50)
        self.heart1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        hearts1 = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
        self.heart1.setMovie(hearts1)
        hearts1.start()
        self.heart1.move(80, 0)
        self.heart1.resize(50, 50)
        self.heart2 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        hearts2 = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
        self.heart2.setMovie(hearts2)
        hearts2.start()
        self.heart2.move(140, 0)
        self.heart2.resize(50, 50)
        self.heart3 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        hearts3 = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
        self.heart.setMovie(hearts3)
        hearts3.start()
        self.heart3.move(20, 0)
        self.heart3.resize(50, 50)
        self.heart4 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        hearts4 = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
        self.heart4.setMovie(hearts4)
        hearts4.start()
        self.heart4.move(80, 0)
        self.heart4.resize(50, 50)
        self.heart5 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        hearts5 = QtGui.QMovie(":/images/Heart.gif")
        self.heart5.setMovie(hearts5)
        hearts5.start()
        self.heart5.move(140, 0)
        self.heart5.resize(50, 50)





    def correcthandler(self):
        self.cont2.hide()
        self.goback3.hide()
        self.question2()



    def incorrecthandler(self):
        self.cont.hide()
        self.goback.hide()
        self.question2()



    def timeouthandler(self):
        self.cont1.hide()
        self.goback2.hide()
        self.question2()



    def question2(self):
        self.pic4.hide()
        self.pic3.show()
        self.pic6.hide()
        self.pic5.hide()
        if len(heartlosscount) == 1:
            self.heart2.hide()
        elif len(heartlosscount) == 2:
            self.heart2.hide()
            self.heart1.hide()
        elif len(heartlosscount) == 3:
            self.heart2.hide()
            self.heart1.hide()
            self.heart.hide()
        else: 
            print len(heartlosscount)



    def scorecheck(self, sendercheck):
        wronganswers = [] 
        correctanswers = []
        if sendercheck == ( self.answ or self.answ1 ):
            wronganswers.append(1)


        if sendercheck == ( self.answ2 ):
            correctanswers.append(1)


        self.wronganswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel("Incorrect: " + str(len(wronganswers)), self)
        self.wronganswerlabel.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)

        self.correctanswerlabel = QtGui.QLabel("Correct: " + str(len(correctanswers)), self)
        self.correctanswerlabel.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)

        summary = len(correctanswers) - len(wronganswers)
        self.summarylabel = QtGui.QLabel("Score: " + str(summary), self)
        self.summarylabel.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 200)





    def gameover(self):
        self.tmr.stop()
        self.Timeout(self)
        self.incorrect(self)
        self.Correct(self)
        self.cont.hide()
        self.cont1.hide()
        self.cont2.hide()
        self.goback3.hide()
        self.goback2.hide()
        self.goback.hide()
        self.pic2.hide()
        self.pic3.hide()
        self.pic4.hide()
        self.pic5.hide()
        self.pic6.hide()
        self.gameoverpic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.gameoverpic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/Gameover.png"))
        self.gameoverpic.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        self.gameoverpic.show()
        self.name = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.name.setGeometry(610, 600, 110, 50)
        self.name.setObjectName('name')
        self.name.setStyleSheet("#name { font-size: 30pt; background-color : cyan; color : yellow; border: none; }")
        self.name.setMaxLength(8)
        self.submit = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.submit.setObjectName('submit')
        self.submit.setStyleSheet("#submit {background-image: url(':/images/Submit.png'); border: none; }"
        "#submit:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Submit_1.png'); }"
        "#submit:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Submit_3.png'); }")
        self.submit.setGeometry(980, 610, 300, 100)
        self.submit.clicked.connect(self.submitcheck)
        self.name.show()
        self.submit.show()



    #def submitcheck(self):
        #if ( len(self.name.text()) < 3 ):

        # Daamate ro ar aris sakmarisi.





    def gobackfunc(self):
        self.hide()
        self.__init__()




def startup():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

startup()
```

---

I think that it's because I didn't append string to array globally.

If thats the problem, how can I do so?

Comment: Try putting `global heartlosscount` after you define your function

Comment: Why use a list for heartlosscount instead of an integer?

Comment: @Ben i am using it in multiple functions, so i have defined it in __init__ function.

Comment: @Jérôme I have made a very big code, Hearts are going in background when connected to specific function with window size picture, I redefine hearts in there with other function and then use list to determine which hearts are hidden and which ones are not.

Comment: Write function, class - what ever that will track hearts for you. That way you can say if something was lost, and when. Since all that will be in a single place you can add kind of optimization, and have particular number in hand.

Comment: Yes i have defined the function that tracks hearts using boolean, but thats not the problem, arrays would be organized, useful and easier to use without messing up code too much. @MichałZaborowski

Comment: @ShellRox - Sorry for messing a bit. You need to track state - that lists, all around. And you need common solution for them. One way is to pass that list each time - to the method, class - depends what you need. Your approach, with global, goes to having single list. I'm saying that you can put class there, with responsibility of taking care of hearts, counting them, tracking losses, printing out what is going on... Single place to do that tasks sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @MichałZaborowski i have made a scorecheck and checkifout functions, one tracks for score and second checks if all hearts are out. You can check full code i just updated.

Comment: @ShellRox - Separate presentation from logic (and each from model). Add methods for updating interface - like presentGameOver, with that hides, and so on... Create separate classes for model - having questions, hearts there. Controller with logic. So user do sth. that goes to controller, where you have your logic, you can check model. Then you can update model. After that presentation picks up data from model - to present it to user.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski i would definitely use those in future, right now i'm beginner in PyQt and Python overall (1 month experience) and the project is so big it will be hard to remodify.

Comment: @ShellRox - looks like that. I did same programs at start. That was Pascal - more then 20y. ago. :) I've spotted on that refactoring, because - from that perspective - right code organization makes many things easier. Good luck! Setup project on github - share sources - that way you can present whole solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you wanted `somefunction` work this way:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def home(self):
        self.heartlosscount = []

    def somefunction(self):
        if len(heartlosscount) == 1:
            self.heart2.hide()
            self.heartlosscount.append(2)
        elif len(heartlosscount) == 2:
            self.heart2.hide()
            self.heart1.hide()
            self.heartlosscount.append(3)
        elif len(heartlosscount) == 3:
            self.heart2.hide()
            self.heart1.hide()
            self.heart.hide()
        else: 
            self.heart2.hide()
            self.heartlosscount.append(1)
```

Note, that your `global` definition can be removed. It does nothing.
Apart from that, your code has another problem.
When `heartlosscount` is empty or has length 1 you take the same action
(`self.heart2.hide()`). I guess you want to do different things in these cases.

Comment: It does the same thing, i replaced first code with this one, perhaps i need to edit something in second one? also without defining heartlosscount as global, it gives me this stderr: `NameError: global name 'heartlosscount' is not defined` @mkiever

Comment: @ShellRox Then you have left something important out in your question. The code I posted runs without error (if you replace all the undefined `self.heart...` by print statements, of course). Try only the posted code, convert the `self.heart...` lines to print and add calls to `somefunction`.

Comment: There were actually 6 hearts, even though they were all same, i added heart3, heart4 and heart5 now and made other 3 hidden, but now it only shows the first one, but prints that only final one was executed, which hides heart5 (final): http://pastebin.com/WcaHyj7j

Comment: @ShellRox: So everything is inside a class. Then use `self` to hand `heartlosscount` around. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks now question2 would recognize appended variable to list (which answered my question), but heart would still add when going on question2, i guess i'l make a new question when i find out exact problem. Thanks!